# CN 202852656 U_ Glass Bottle Light Patent

Tags: patent-infringement, cn202852656

My question is regarding the above patent number (CN 202852656 U); does this patent prevent anyone from making and selling glass bottles filled with lights?  The reason I ask is because I am interested in inserting lights into bottles and decorating the outside of the bottle.  Would I be able to make these decorated bottles and sell them, or is that infringement?

Thank you,
Melissa

Comment: @Mellisa Then you should give an up-vote. And possibly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Chinese patent document number. Patents are territorial rights so unless you are planning to make, sell, import, or use this in China this isn't relevant. There may be similar patents in other locations but this one is just enforceable in China.